# Postfix chroot dns resolve problem (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Postfix 3.3.0)

Tags: dns, postfix-mta, chroot

I have a Postfix setup configured with chroot=y in master.cf file(full original config). When the chroot is enabled, the DNS resolvation not work (the sender is from valid, popular service):
"postfix/smtpd[19114]: connect from unknown[X.X.X.X]"

Possible solutions that i tried:

- copy /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_* and needed lib files to the jail(/var/spool/postfix/...)
- with systemd-resolved and replaced with resolvconf package (for testing)
- static /etc/resolv.conf (not /run/systemd/system/resolv.conf symlink)
- various possibilites in nsswitch.conf

The hosts file is working in chroot mode, i've tested with static entries.

Any other possible solutions?

Thanks for the help.

Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the solution.

If your system run ZFS or have any separated partitions (like /var/spool), than you need to make sure that partion (where is the postfix chroot) have exec rights.

Defaults are usually enough for the ext4 file system, zfs need exec flag.

Answer (score 0):

Running `/usr/lib/postfix/configure-instance.sh` will copy library and config files needed for chroot to `/var/spool/postfix`.